# Find point along x axis where yz plane flips to back facing after perspective projection. Have a solution but don't know why it works

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

I am trying to find the point along the x axis where a plane with normal pointing along the x axis would flip to back facing after perspective projection. Essentially the red line in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ3yi.png) image.

My first attempt to find it I just sampled along the x axis checking if a triangle there was back facing after projection. This only gave me an approximation but I could make the approximation as accurate as I wanted by just sampling more planes so I used this as a baseline to verify other solutions.

I then tried the following:

```
vec4 center = projection.inverse()*vec4(0,0,0,1);
center /= center.w;
float d = dot(center.xyz, vec3(1,0,0));
vec3 point = vec3(1,0,0)*d;
```

But this did not work, it was close but not right. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzYhG.png), the red line is the sampled point and the blue is the one calculated from that.

I then tried changing the calculation for center to `projection.inverse()*vec4(0,0,-1,1)` to see what that would look like. With the the sampled point in red, the blue line being the previous version and the green the new version. I got the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oJkU.png) which as you can see is still not correct.

But I noticed that the green was always directly between the blue and the red so I tried the following.

```
vec4 c1 = projection.inverse()*vec4(0,0,0,1);
c1 /= c1.w;
float d1 = dot(c1.xyz, vec3(1,0,0));
vec4 c2 = projection.inverse()*vec4(0,0,-1,1);
c2 /= c2.w;
float d2 = dot(c2.xyz, vec3(1,0,0));
float d = (d2-d1)*2 + d1;
vec3 point = vec3(1,0,0)*d;
```

Which seems to be correct but I have no idea why that works. It is always extremely close to the sampled point so I assume it is correct.

My question is why does this work?

Comment: Wouldn't it be just the x coordinate of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you have to project worldspace camera position on line. The position of projection would be the point where normals flip.

[image]

Having arbitrary point on line, normalized line direction and camera pos you can do following:

```
float d = dot(CamPos.xyz - LinePos.xyz, NrmLineDir.xyz);
vec3 point = LinePos.xyz + NrmLineDir.xyz * d;
```

I think what you did was overcomplicated solution of what I wrote here, so removing some of the code would result in same solution.